# How can I create a new array by merging specific values

Tags: java, arrays

I have created two arrays with values in them.

```
String[] array1 = {"ab", "bc", "ca"};
String[] array2 = {"zy", "yx", "xz"};
```

I would like to create a third array that obtains specific values from the two arrays.

```
{"ab", "ca", "yx"}
```

Instead of simply merging two arrays, is there a way that I can pluck specific values from other arrays when creating the third array?

Comment: Java or javascript? What have you tried so far?

Comment: You need to be more precise about what the rules are. Are you simply taking every other element?

Comment: What do you mean by "specific values"?

Comment: Have you tried iterating through the arrays and selecting the desired values?

Comment: you really should show the code that you have created and have people help you with that, not pose questions and take code from someone else.  Spirit of stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

### In Java

You would need to define an interface by which you decide which item is specific and which is not.

```
public interface SpecificItemDetect{
    boolean isSpecific(String item);
}
```

Now, you can use this code to create your third array.

```
List<String> third = new ArrayList<String>();

for (String item : Array1){
    if(detector.isSpecific(item)){
        third.add(item);
    }
}

for (String item : Array2){
    if(detector.isSpecific(item)){
        third.add(item);
    }
}

// Now, you may want to convert the list to array.
String[] thirdArray = new String[third.size()];
third.toArray(thirdArray);
```

**Note:** `detector` in this example is an implementation of a class which implements the interface `SpecificItemDetect`.

### In JavaScript

In JavaScript you would need a function instead of that interface. Something like this:

```
var filter = function(item){
    if(/* item is specific */){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And create the third array like this:

```
var third = [];

for (var i = 0, len = Array1.length; i < len; i += 1){
    if(filter(Array1[i])){
        third.push(item);
    }
}

for (var i = 0, len = Array2.length; i < len; i += 1){
    if(filter(Array2[i])){
        third.push(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the memory where the array values are stored. This means, you need to go through the array name. Now, with array name you can refer to a specific value you want to 'pluck'. Do you have any rules for this??

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not entirely sure what you mean when you say specific values, but if you mean the values that you showed only then you can do it this way

```
String[] array1 = {"ab", "bc", "ca"};
String[] array2 = {"zy", "yx", "xz"};
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] array3 = new String[list1.size()]; //Skip if you don't need array

list1.add(array1[0]);
list1.add(array1[2]);
list1.add(array2[1]);


list1.toArray(array3); //Skip if you don't need array
```

Much like what abforce said, but if you simply wanted to know how to use the .add method, that is all you need to do. But if you would like to change the values inside when the "specific values" you need change then the interface will be much better. This code is simiple but not very flexible if you need to change the values in the future.